# Antlr parser choose incorrect rule before reaching end of the line

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr4, antlr4cs

I'm trying to write grammar to some kind of assembler language but not using mnemonics.

I have some kind of registers, lets say:

```
a, b, c, d
```

And one special register, which keeps address in memory:

```
&e
```

Now I want to allow to assign values to them:

```
a = b
d = a
c = &e
```

`a` is also a special register (accumulator), so it can has some operations made only on it like:

```
a = a xor d
```

all of them has `a` on the left side and one of the all registers on the right side.
I

My grammar:

```
grammar somename;
options {
    language = CSharp;
}
program: line* EOF;

line: statement (NEWLINE+ | EOF);

statement: aOperation | registerAssignment;

expression:
    or #orAssignment
    | xor #xorAssignment;


xor:
    XOR reg8;

reg: hl_read | REGISTER8;

aOperation: REG_A '=' REG_A expression;

registerAssignment: reg '=' reg;

REGISTER:
    REG_A
    | 'b'
    | 'c'
    | 'd';

e_read: E_READ;

REG_A: 'a';
OR: 'or';
XOR: 'xor';
E_READ: '&e';
WHITESPACE: (' ' | '\t')+ -> skip;
NEWLINE: ('\r'? '\n' | '\r');
```

Now I've got a problem, that parser always catch a line `a = a xor b` as a = b and next round of parser get b register and there is nothing on the right side and throws error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in Program.dll: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'`
How can I fix this?

Comment: Your lexer will never produce a `REG_A` token because the `REGISTER` rule takes precedence. So `aOperation` can't match because the token you get is a `REGISTER`, but `aOperation` needs a `REG_A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by sepp2k: the lexer will never produce a `REG_A` token because the input `'a'` would already be consumed by the `REGISTER` rule.

A solution would be to remove the `REGISTER` lexer rule and create a `register` parser rule:

```
register
 : REG_A
 | REG_B
 | REG_C
 | REG_D
 ;

REG_A: 'a';
REG_B: 'b';
REG_C: 'c';
REG_D: 'd';
```

Comment: Thank you, I've rewritten my grammar according to your comment and now it works perfectly.